# What is a good wiring configuration to minimize noise on an analog DC signal?

Tags: sensor, wiring, signal-to-noise

I am measuring a photodiode with a high precision ADC, but they are currently 0.5-1m apart. The voltage will be constant. I would like to take the measurements as quick as possible so it would be good to reduce noise rather rely on software to extract the value.

I have been looking into some of the different cables like twisted pair, coax or parallel, but they are targeted towards high frequency signals rather than DC.

Are there wiring configurations that would be good in this situation or would making a separate board for the ADC next to the photodiode be the better solution?

Comment: What are the noise threats your cable might encounter? What is the bandwidth of your signal (don't say 0 Hz or DC - think about it).

Comment: @Andyaka There are no major noise threats. Just proximity to digital micro controllers/ADCs, mains, and other computer equipment. Possibly interference with the supply power in the cable. I'm sorry I'm not sure what you mean by bandwidth. Are you saying the photodiode voltage won't be constant? Or in regards the frequency of measurement?

Comment: @Andyaka The photodiode will be exposed to a different light level as soon as a solid measurement has been made. I expect this to be in the 10Hz range but ideally it would be closer to 1000Hz.

Comment: Twisted pair etc are targeted towards *rejecting interference* from high frequency signals. Nothing wrong with using them to connect a DC signal.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Would one be better than the others in this circumstance? Would that make shielded twisted pair about as good as it gets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to establish the precise nature of the system noises in terms of how they might superimpose on your signal and you need to do it for each cabling scenario to get a definitive answer. But, it doesn't sound like you know the numbers so you then have to decide what are the likely better options.

The likely worst option is plain ordinary untwisted parallel wires. The better cabling solutions are coax and twisted pair with a screen over the twisted pair being the potentially best candidate but this requires balanced differential signalling down the cable and this may be as complex as the best solution which is to fit the ADC up at the photodiode.

Even with the ADC up at the photodiode you might need to improve things by opto-isolating the whole thing (power and data) so that there is very little influence that noise can make. Check out ADI's set of digital/power isolators - I think they are called ADuMxxxx where xxxx is the number of the various parts they offer.